# Pagination error url was not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I created a Pagination in Codeigniter, because I would like 2 news in one page and 2 news other page etc...

So, here is my **Model:**

```
class Country extends CI_Model
 {
    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

public function record_count() {
    return $this->db->count_all("news");
}

public function fetch_countries($limit, $start) {
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get("news");

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
   }
}
```

I can see my news. My problem is if I want to move to the next page, I will get an error that url was not found welcome/index/2 (its the second page). localhost/codeigniter/ -> this is my homepage and the news are revealed on the homepage. It is possible to see the news but when I want to scroll to the next page then it gives the error.

**Controller:**

```
  public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('news_model');
    $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    $this->load->model("Country");
    $this->load->library("pagination");
}


public function index()
{
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "welcome/index";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->Country->record_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 2;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $data["results"] = $this->Country->
        fetch_countries($config["per_page"], $page);
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
    $data['title'] = 'News archive';

    $this->load->view('index', $data);

}
```

And finally the **View:**

```
  <?php
foreach($results as $data) {
echo $data->title . " - " . $data->text . "<br>";
}
?>
```

I hope I was clear, but if not, then please ask, and I will edit the question.

Comment: You recive notice,warnings,error in apache-error.log or php-fpm.log or nginx-error.log?

Comment: You can show `var_dump($result)` in you view

Comment: `$this->pagination` instance true class?

Comment: I just dont know where to reveal the next page of news

two links: http://kepfeltoltes.hu/160202/news2_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg

http://kepfeltoltes.hu/160202/news_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg

Comment: You can show you .htaccess file?

Comment: I delete my answer this answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine my guess you did not configure your routes. The [URI Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)

```
 $route['welcome/(:any)'] = 'welcome/index/$1';
```

If you just have welcome that will detect index function

```
 $config["base_url"] = base_url('welcome');
```

Base Url

```
 $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';
```

Comment: My routes:

$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['welcome/(:any)'] = 'welcome/index/$1';

My config:
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter';

Comment: With your base_url might be typo error in your comment but do you have `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/';` it good to have / at end of project